# Docker getting Selenium to run

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a python script with Selenium inside docker. Since the script is in a docker container, I keep getting this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver'
>   executable needs to be in PATH.

The code works just fine, when I run it on my computer and use the `PATH` to the chromedriver file, however a docker container can't see the `PATH` as it is isolated. I would use a pre-made docker image, however I need other dependencies for my code to run such as smtplib, imapclient, and beautifulsoup to name a few.

Is there a command that will tell Selenium that the chromedriver is in the same folder as the script, or some other way to make it visible to docker?

Answer (score 1):

Docker container is a like a VM. Inside the image you have scripts. But not chromedriver. I would say do not copy the chromedriver inside the image. Just copying the `chromedriver` alone will not work.

Instead use `selenium/node-chrome` image and give the container name as the host to your container.

Take a look at this example.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-run-multiple-test-suites-using-docker-compose/

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention the other dependencies my program has. Is there a way I can view the dockerfile for this docker image?

Comment: @Toby Here's a link to the docker file for selenium/node-chrome on github: [selenium/node-chrome](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/NodeChrome/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code snippet to set the path to the chrome driver within your script:

```
import os

path_to_chrome_driver = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chrome_driver )
```